# Are one-off openings and endings expensive to produce?

Tags: anime-production, theme-song

At least two recent anime series have had openings (OPs) or endings (EDs) that were unique to a single episode.  The OP to *Erased* episode 11 was modified for dramatic purpose to carry over the suspense beginning in episode 10.  Every ED for *ReLIFE* had its own custom music, combined with a mixture of repeated and custom visuals. I am sure there have been other series to do this sort of thing.

As a fan, I appreciate the extra effort the studios take in producing special OPs and EDs. And it is likely the artistic staff at the anime studios enjoy offering their fans these special glimpses into their series. From a production standpoint, though, I wonder how much extra cost a special OP or ED adds. Do they expect that enhanced fan appreciation due to these things will result in higher returns?  Or are they, like the artistic folks, doing it "for the fun of it"?

Comment: It completely depends on the quality, duration and reuse of animations, backdrops and music.

Comment: @Hakase True.  *Erased* would have been cheap. It was only one episode, and the OP's music did not change.  The visuals were only altered in one aspect. For *ReLIFE* though, they had to license, buy, and/or self-produce 13 songs (or have them donated) and spend time on each ED to choose the images to use as well as their order and duration.

Comment: Unlikely they were donated, and all of the ED songs were real JPop hits from the 90s-00s so not self-produced. I would guess that licencing 1 song for 13 episodes is cheaper than 13 songs for 1 episode each, but that would have been budgeted for.

Comment: A bit more extreme example is [all 12 EDs of *Akuma no Riddle*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3OMtTklBOc) having different visual and original music depending on the episode's main character(s).

Comment: Related: https://www.sportskeeda.com/anime/why-chainsaw-man-different-endings-episode-explained